# Adding a column name in a dataframe which is attached?

Tags: r, igraph

So i currently have a dataframe in R where:

```
      degree

54     0.65
43     0.76
31     0.67
```

and by executing:

```
df[1]
```

it prints out the first row:

```
54       0.65
```

I'm trying to assign a column name to the first column, where i get:

```
vertex     degree

  54        0.65
  43        0.76
  31        0.67
```

So i can query the dataframe column separately:

```
df$vertex
df$degree
```

Is there any possible ways i could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rownames_to_column`

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df1, 'vertex')
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
data.frame(df1, vertex = row.names(df1))
```